# Location services alertview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When we use libraries of location services in our app it automatically show the alert box when we launch the app with don't allow and Ok buttons.

Is it possible to disable the don't allow button? And is there any variable set when we press don't allow or OK button?

Comment: that's is internal to the MapKit Framework .. you cant do anything in that regard.

Comment: how can i check those variables @AnkitSrivastava

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean when the alert asks the user if they want to allow your application to use location services ? If so then no, you cannot override this. This is so that the user is not only aware that their location is benign tracked but also that this data is going to be used by the application. Would you want an application tracking you and potentially uploaded your location without your knowledge ?

As for the variables, pressing yes will tell iOS that it is allowed to track you data, saying no will do the opposite so any maps or locations based services will not be able to retrieve user location.

Comment: how can i check those variables

Comment: This will check to see if your app is allowed location services, if not then prompt the user to enable it :

MKUserLocation *userLocation = map.userLocation;
BOOL locationAllowed = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
BOOL locationAvailable = userLocation.location != nil;

Comment: if (!locationAllowed) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR: Location Service Disabled" 
                                                        message:@"Go to settings > location services - To relabel location based services for this application." 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

Comment: //Handle exception:
else {
        if (!locationAvailable) 
            [self.map.userLocation addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"location" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:nil];
    }